# Different browsers show different page heights

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I'm trying to design a single page website (without a vertical & a horizontal scroll). Now my structure is:

```
container-->height: 100%
   header-->height: 10%
   main-content-->height: 80%
   footer-->height: 10%
```

The page appears exactly what I want in **Mozilla Firefox**. 
However, in **Chrome** a black space (about `1-2px`) appears between the footer bottom and the browser bottom.
In **Safari**, a vertical scroller appears on the right.

I'm working on windows and have not applied any margin/padding{top or bottom} to any of the elements.

**EDIT#1**

I'm also using a slider in the `main-content` for which I had to specify fixed height for some divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason to why you get black space at bottom or a scrollbar is the way browsers work with percentages calculations. You can find an explanation [Here](http://palantir.net/blog/responsive-design-s-dirty-little-secret).

The trick will be to define #footer outside of container and set

`#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9%;
    }`

And also set height of #header to 9% to allow for contingency in calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that "main-content" should have a height of 80% (which adds up nicely with the two 10% values), but nowhere in your code (either HTML or CSS) have you actually specified 80%.

What I *can* see in "main-content" are a bunch of nested DIVs, all with fixed-pixel heights specified, so I'm not sure how this was ever going to work.

Start by adding `height: 80%;` to `#main-content`, get rid of all the fixed heights for all DIVs nested inside `#main-content`, and then work out what needs to be done next.

**EDIT:** You mention that your code works in FireFox, but the only thing I can think of is that it works at *the exact pixel size of your FireFox window*, and no other sizes. If you resize your FireFox window, does it still look OK?

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I resize the window. I didn't include the `javascript` for page-correction in the jsfiddle code here, that adjusts to itself when I resize the window.

Also, the `fixed` heights are there for a slider that I'm using. It won't work unless they are of a fixed height in `px`. Maybe, that is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of web development. I suggest starting with a CSS reset to ensure a consistent layout. If you aren't inclined to use Yahoo's tools, a Google of `CSS reset` is a great place to start.

Yahoo offers nice tools to facilitate: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/.

> The foundational YUI Reset CSS file removes and neutralizes the
>   inconsistent default styling of HTML elements, creating a level
>   playing field across A-grade browsers and providing a sound foundation
>   upon which you can explicitly declare your intentions.

```
<!-- Source File -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
```

Comment: I'd already done that. Please see the edited question. My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/a7bqh/

Answer (score -1):

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, big, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,table, tr, td, th, tbody, thead, tfooter,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend, caption,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; border-spacing: 0; }
```

use this as a reset, it should work